# How to retrieve only one column from collection in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to retrieve only ID column with value less than 4,

```
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("d");

     MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> contCol = database.getCollection("test");
     BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
     query.put("ID",1);

 FindIterable<org.bson.Document> it = contCol.find().projection(excludeId());
```

Doesn't give me the required output. The collection *test* has two columns, namely *ID* and *name*; the query is returning both the columns, I want to get only the *ID* column.

Comment: What are you getting now ? What do you expect ?

Comment: collection test has two columns namely ID,name, i am now getting both the columns, I want to get only ID column                                                              http://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify which columns you want included, you need to specify that in your projection; for example using the [include() method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html#include-java.lang.String...-).

Comment: helped me a bit ,but i want to exclude objectid for which i did like this:                                        `MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> contCol = database.getCollection("test");
 BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
 fields.put("_id", 0);
 FindIterable<org.bson.Document> it = contCol.find(fields).projection(Projections.include("ID"));`    How can i exclude _id ?                                                                                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/users/174843/vince-bowdren

Comment: The projection methods, listed on the page I linked, have everything you need to specify exactly which fields you want the query to return. And _the  example at the top of that page_ is a perfect example for your purposes.